# How to add menu to a widget derived from Qwidget

Tags: qt, qt4, menu, symbian, nokia

i want to know how to add menu to a widget, which is derived from Qwidget in QT symbian,

i know how to add menu to window derived from Qwindow, but i am not getting for widget

derived from Qwidget

pls help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

QMainWindow provides you convenience function to add and manage a QMenuBar.

With a window that inherits from QWidget (instead of QMainWindow) you need to achieve this by yourself. You can add the menu bar in the window layout like any other QWidget using the function [add](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qlayout.html#add). By playing with the layouts you can place QMenuBar at the top of the window.
An other way can be to use a [QToolBar](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qtoolbar.html).